# Understanding Big O notation - Cracking the coding interview example 9

Tags: algorithm, tree, big-o, notation

I got stuck with this two codes.

**Code 1**

```
int f(int n){
    if (n <= 1){
         return 1;
    }
    return f(n-1) + f(n-1);
}
```

**Code 2** (Balanced binary search tree)

```
int sum(Node node){
    if(node == null){
        return 0;
    }
    return sum(node.left) + node.value + sum(node.right);
}
```

the author says the runtime of Code 1 is O(2^n) and space complexity is O(n)

And Code 2 is O(N)

I have no idea what's different between those two codes. it looks like both are the same binary trees

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well there's a mistake because the first snippet runs in O(2^n) not O(n^2).

The explanation is:
In every step we decrement `n` but create twice the number of calls, so for n we'll call twice with f(n-1) and for each one of the calls of n-1 we'll call twice with f(n-2) - which is 4 calls, and if we'll go another level down we'll call 8 times with f(n-3): so the number of calls is: 2^1, then 2^2, then 2^3, 2^4, ..., 2^n.

The second snippet is doing one pass on a binary tree and reaches every node exactly once, so it's O(n).

Comment: then is Perfect Binary Tree O(2^n) ? Because i think it has the same structure with the first one

Comment: @Daniel the first one has nothing to do with trees. The second is a binary tree but it doesn't have to be balanced. When we state that it's O(n) we consider `n` as the number of nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it's important to understand what N is in both cases. 
In the first example it's pretty obvious, because you see it directly in the code. For your first case, if you build the tree of `f(i)` calls, you'll see that it contains `O(2^N)` elements. Indeed,

```
            f(N)             // 1 node
        /          \ 
   f(N-1)         f(N-1)     // 2 nodes
  /      \      /      \
f(N-2) f(N-2)  f(N-2) f(N-2) // 2^2 nodes
...
f(1) ........ f(1)           // 2^(N-1) nodes
```

In the second case, N is (most likely) a number of elements in the tree. As you may see from the code, we walk through every element exactly once - you may realize it as you see that `node.value` is invoked once for each tree node. Hence O(N).

Note that in such tasks **N** normally means **the size of the input**, while what the **input** is depends on your problem. It can be just a number (like in your first problem), a one-dimensional array, a binary tree (like in your second problem), or even a matrix (although in the latter case you may expect to see explicit statement like "a matrix with a size M*N").

So your confusion probably comes from the fact that the "definition of N" differs between those two problems. In other words, I might say that `n2 = 2^n1`.

Comment: Upvote for explicitly stating the root of OP's problem: difference in definitions of N

Comment: Seems to me that the main source of confusion was that the OP thought that the first code represents a binary tree as well.

Comment: I have the feeling that (for the first example) this is still another definition of N. The book refers to N as the depth of the tree, not as the input value. So for f(4) the tree has a depth of N=3 (not 4). The number of nodes (or calls) is `2^(depth+1) - 1`. That's `2^4 - 1 = 15`. I admit to be somewhat confused about the explanation though.

Answer (score 1):

The first code is indeed `O(2^n)`.

But the second code cannot be `O(n)`, because there is no `n` there. That's a thing which many forget and usually they *assume* what `n` is without clarifying it.

In fact you can estimate growth speed of anything based on anything. Sometimes it's a size of input (which in the first code is `O(1)` or `O(log n)` depending on usage of big numbers), sometimes just on argument if it's numeric.

So when we start thinking about what time and memory depend on in the second code we can get these things:

1. `time=O(number_of_nodes_in_tree)`
2. `time=O(2^height_of_tree)`
3. `additional_space=O(height_of_tree)`
4. `additional_space=O(log(number_of_nodes))` (if the tree is balanced)

All of them are correct at the same time - they just relate something to different things.

Comment: "they assume what n is without clarifying it" - you're right, that we shouldn't assume anything but since `n` in the second case means "the number of nodes in the tree" it's pretty trivial and hence sometimes neglected to be mentioned or even intentionally not mentioned to reduce verbosity ;)

Answer (score 1):

You’re confused between the “N” of the two cases. In the first case, the N refers to the input given. So for instance, if N=4, then the number of the functions being called is 2^4=16. You can draw the recursive map to illustrate. Hence O(2^N).

In the second case, the N refers to the number of nodes in the binary tree. So this N has no relation with the input but the amount of nodes that already exists in the binary tree. So when user calls the function, it visits every node exactly once. Hence O(N).

Comment: "if N=4, then the number of the functions being called is 2^4=16". This doesn't seem correct to me. If N=4, the f() function is called 15 times. You can draw the tree to visualize it.

Answer (score 0):

Code 1:

The `if()` statement runs `n` times according to whatever is passed into the parameter, but the the function call itself `n-1` times. To simplify:

`n * (n-1) = n^2 - n = O(n^2 - n) = O(n^2)`

Code 2:

The search traverses every element of the tree only once, and the function itself doesn't have any `for()`. Since there are `n` items and they are visited only once, it is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

For Code 2, to determine the Big O of a function, didn't we have to consider the cost of the recurrence and also how many times the recurrence was run?

If we use two approach to estimate the Big O using recursive tree and master theorem:

Recursive tree:
total cost in each level will be cn for each level as the number of recursive call and the fraction of input are equal, and the level of tree is lg(n) since it's a balanced binary search tree. So the run time should be nlg(n)?

Master Theorem:
This should be a case 2 since f(n) = n^logbase a (b). So according to the master theorem, it should be nlg(n) running time?

Answer (score 0):

We can think of it as `O(2^Depth)`.

In the first example: The depth is `N`, which happens to be the input of the problem mentioned in the book.

In the second example: It is a balanced binary search tree, hence, it has `Log(N)` levels (depth). Note: `N` is the number of elements in the tree.

=> Let's apply our `O(2^Depth)`.. `O(2^(Log(N)) = O(N)` leaving us with `O(N)` complexity.

Reminder:

- In computer science we usually refer to `Log2(n)` as `Log(n)`.
- The logarithm of x in base b is the exponent you put on b to get x as a result.

In the above complexity: `O(2^(Log(N)`, we're raising the base 2 to `Log2(N)` which gives us N. (Check the two reminders)

This [link](https://brownmath.com/alge/loglaws.htm#def2) can be useful.

Comment: "The depth is N, which happens to be the input of the problem mentioned in the book". Are you sure about this? The depth of a tree is the number of edges from the root node to the most distant leaf node. So for the tree represented in the book the depth should be 3 (not 4). Do you agree?